# $push and $set not executing simultaneously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

`$push` and `$set` is not working together. Fields corresponds to $push is appending the values, but $ set is not updating the values correspond to its fields

```
Parcel.findOneAndUpdate({
            $and: [{
                "parcelStatus.status": {
                    $ne: "undelivered"
                }
            }, {
                "_id": req.body.consignmentNumber
            }]
        }, {
            $push: {
                "request": {
                    reason: req.body.request[0].reason,
                    date: new Date(),
                    requestType: 'Changing delivery Address'
                }
            }
        }, {
            $set: {
                destAddress: req.body.destAddress
            }
        }, function(err, parcel) {
            console.log("oldParcel" + JSON.stringify(parcel));
```

Comment: The second argument should be the modification object. Combine the `$push` and `$set` into a single object.

Answer (score 0):

Third param is to pass options. you should use `$set` and `$push` both in second param

can try this one:

```
Parcel.findOneAndUpdate({$and :[{"parcelStatus.status": {$ne:"undelivered"}},{"_id" : req.body.consignmentNumber}]},
  {
    $push:{"request": {reason: req.body.request[0].reason,
      date: new Date(),
      requestType: 'Changing delivery Address'}},
    $set: {destAddress : req.body.destAddress}
  },
  {new:true}, 
  function(err, parcel) {
    console.log("newParcel" + JSON.stringify(parcel));
  })
```